# [Spring boot ]Error in native query with join spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have a many to many relationship in spring boot with User and Role. I have three tables in database (Role_utilisateur, users_roles and utilisateurs). In my repository, ireturn List of my entite called RoleEntite which have two attributes (nom and id).

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ROLE_UTILISATEUR.NOM, ROLE_UTILISATEUR.ROLE_ID " + "FROM ROLE_UTILISATEUR "
            + "INNER JOIN USERS_ROLES on users_roles.role_id = ROLE_UTILISATEUR.ROLE_ID "
            + "INNER JOIN UTILISATEURS on utilisateurs.utilisateur_id = USERS_ROLES.UTILISATEUR_ID "
            + "WHERE UTILISATEURS.UTILISATEUR_ID = :userId", nativeQuery = true)
    List<RoleEntite> findUsersRolesNative(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

When i call my function in

```
private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(UserEntite user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        List<RoleEntite> roleList = userRepository.findUsersRolesNative(user.getId());
        for (RoleEntite roleEntite : roleList) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roleEntite.getNom()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
```

I get this error in my java eclipse

**org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.id.firstSpringBoot.entite.RoleEntite] for value '{ADMIN, 1}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.id.firstSpringBoot.entite.RoleEntite]**

[image]

[image]

How can i resolve this error and get the name ADMIN in my function getGrantedAuthorities can do this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're selecting two columns and returning a list of entities. You need to either select the entity in your query or return the list of two values in a collection.

To return entities you would need to convert your query to JPQL. The following is a JPQL representation of your native query.
I've had to do some guessing for the joins (I assume you have some JPA related entities):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT RoleEntite r "
        + "INNER JOIN UserRole r.user u "
        + "INNER JOIN Utilisateurs u.Utilisateur x "
        + "WHERE x.UTILISATEUR_ID = :userId")
List<RoleEntite> findUsersRolesNative(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

If you go the native query route:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ROLE_UTILISATEUR.NOM, ROLE_UTILISATEUR.ROLE_ID " + "FROM ROLE_UTILISATEUR "
        + "INNER JOIN USERS_ROLES on users_roles.role_id = ROLE_UTILISATEUR.ROLE_ID "
        + "INNER JOIN UTILISATEURS on utilisateurs.utilisateur_id = USERS_ROLES.UTILISATEUR_ID "
        + "WHERE UTILISATEURS.UTILISATEUR_ID = :userId", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findUsersRolesNative(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

The returned list should yield:

```
for (Object[] obj : list) {
 nom = obj[0];
 roleId = obj[1];
 // ... do what ever you want with the values
```

}

Comment: Hello @Hopey One , can you give me an example where I can have both of your solution's. can you take my sql request and tell me exactly how can i modify it, please.